# who knows how I can get the code for a message box?

Tags: javascript, php, html

By message box I mean a box that allows users to write their contents and have various options such as BOLD, ITALIC, color, justify, etc., to modify their message's text!
(Just like the box used when posting a question or answer on Stack Overflow)

Comment: There's this thing called [Google](http://google.com)

Comment: Can you post your code. your question is very unclear about what you want. do you mean a <textarea> ?

Comment: Likely most readers of this post know....but that's just not how things work here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nicedit](http://nicedit.com/demos.php) and [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php) do a pretty nice job: you can get the code from their sites. There's also a good list [here](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/design/10-best-wysiwyg-text-and-html-editors-for-your-next-project/).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Anyhow, sorry for my basic question, I'm new in programming and I do not know how things work here

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/help) might help. Also, if you liked my answer, please click the greyed-out checkmark next to it so that we both gain [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can put textarea with styles:

```
<textarea style="font-size: 24px;" type="text" name="art_text"/></textarea>
```